# Unable to load data into table using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Code:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table']);
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $('#get').click(function ($scope)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'JsonProcessor.do',
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $scope.rowCollection = data[0];
                    console.log("Result from Database: ", data[0]);
                    console.log("typeOf json is: " + jQuery.type(data));
                }
            });
            $('#dialog').show();
        });
    });

<div id="dialog" class="bs-example web_dialog">
    <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Unique Id</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Doc Url</th>
                <th>Time Stamp</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
                <td>{{row.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{row.DATE_CREATED}}</td>
                <td>{{row.URL}}</td>
                <td>{{row.TIMESTAMP}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is it because I am not using $http to fetch the data? I tried with $http and it throwing error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $http is not a function(anonymous function)
@ (index):197jQuery.event.dispatch 
@ joint.js:4683jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
@ joint.js:4367
```

Checking the DOM shows only table header and `<tbody>` commented out.

I am guessing angular js is conflicting with jquery functions?

Comment: You show the jQuery code, but don't tell what the problem is. Then you tell what the problem is with the angular code, but don't show the code. Hard to help.

Comment: the `$http` error is because you forgot to inject `$http` to make it available. Using `$.ajax` is outside angular and needs to notify angular of scope changes with `$.apply`

Comment: @JBNizet There's nothing to show. That's all the code I have.

Comment: @charlietfl I tried injecting `$http` as `function ($scope, $http)` but it didn't work so I used `$.ajax` to fetch data. I didn't understand what you meant by notify angular with `$.apply` ??

Comment: You said: *I tried with $http*. I don't see any line of code posted using $http. So, did you try, or didn't you? If you did, where is the code?

Comment: while you *shouldn't* use JQuery and Angular together, you *can*, and they don't generally conflict.  however, JQuery won't tell Angular that a change has been made to it's objects.  you really should consider using `ng-click` instead of `$('#get').click` so that Angular knows the click happened.

Answer (score 1):

Any event outside of angular core that changes the scope needs to notify angular to run a digest cycle to update the view.

Since you are not using angular `$http` to make the ajax request you will need to do this within the success callback

```
success: function (data){
    $scope.rowCollection = data[0];
    $scope.$apply();
    console.log("Result from Database: ", data[0]);
    console.log("typeOf json is: " + jQuery.type(data));
}
```

The error that `$http` is not a function would mean you did not inject `$http` into controller

Comment: Thanks but I just changed code to angular as suggested by @Magus but one problem is table row is created but empty like this: `<td class="ng-binding"></td>`

Comment: Your properties of the data being used in view must be incorrect

Comment: view code shown should work, print the collection in view `<pre>{{rowCollection|json}}</pre>`

Comment: On the back end I am using Hasp map with key value pairs. Is there a way to retrieve key values in angular. I am confused because `console.log(data[0].ID);` is printing the value

Comment: I'm confused to about that. Copy sample of data and create demo that replicates the problem in a sandbox like plunker

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to mix jQuery and Angular. It is not safe and not recommanded by anyone.

Angular can't know that jQuery is working because you use a jQuery listener (with `$('#get').click(...)`). If you want to use Angular, just use it. Use the `ng-click` directive and use the `$http` service.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table']);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.get = function() {
        $http.get('JsonProcessor.do').success(function(data) {
            $scope.rowCollection = data[0];
            console.log("Result from Database: ", data[0]);
            console.log("typeOf json is: " + jQuery.type(data));
        });
        $('#dialog').show();
    });
});

<div id="get" ng-click="get()">GET</div>
<div id="dialog" class="bs-example web_dialog">
    <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Unique Id</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Doc Url</th>
                <th>Time Stamp</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
                <td>{{row.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{row.DATE_CREATED}}</td>
                <td>{{row.URL}}</td>
                <td>{{row.TIMESTAMP}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am able to see the data in `console.log()` but the table is printed like this: `<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection" class="ng-scope">
 <td class="ng-binding"></td>
 <td class="ng-binding"></td>
 <td class="ng-binding"></td>
 <td class="ng-binding"></td>
</tr>`

Comment: So actually there are four rows created but no data displayed